# Can I rely on mongo to consistently handle many $inc from many different sources all updating the same document?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

If I have an update statements like `{$set: {$inc: {myCounter: 1}}}` happening every few seconds in my code, and my code is distributed across 1000 different processes, will mongo (3.16.18) correctly treat all the increments to a single document correctly? Or to put it a different way - if I read the value of myCounter out of the document after all these processes are finished, will the number equal the total number of $inc update commands that were issued to mongo, or is there a possibility that various issues will mean that some of the updates get lost/overwritten?

To put it in concrete terms, if each instance of my code generates 1000 increment commands and I run 1000 instances concurrently, can I expect myCounter to be 1 million at the end (assuming it starts at zero)? If I take the entire scenario and repeat it will myCounter be guaranteed to be the same every time?

If it matters: mongo version is 3.16.18, library is pymongo 3.9.0, and I'll have the read preference set to SECONDARY_PREFERRED.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, yes.